# Using Magic mock to test Github Api

Tags: python, mocking

I am basically using magic mock and context manager to test my code, I was successfully able to mock my get_urls function, But I am having trouble mocking out my access_all_repos_pr(): function which contains data of PR newer than 7 days, can anyone help me out on how to mock that data.

Here is the test code for my get_urls():

```
import unittest
from mock import MagicMock, patch
from contextlib2 import ExitStack
from GithubAPIpackage.GithubAPI import get_urls


class Test_GithubApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_urls_returns_valid_urls(self):
        with ExitStack() as stack:

            mock_get_urls = stack.enter_context(
                patch("GithubAPIpackage.GithubAPI._fetch_url")
            )
            fake_data = {"current_user_repositories_url": "http://FAKEURL.com"}
            mock_get_urls.return_value = fake_data
            print(type(fake_data))

            result = get_urls()
            self.assertEqual(result, "http://FAKEURL.com")
```

I want to mock out the response for the function access_all_repo_pr, can anyone help me out in what I need to do exactly to create a mock for my access_all_repo_pr function. Do I need to refactor my code in some way? (relatively new to python)

what I am trying is:

```
class Test_GithubApi_newer_than_7_days(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_access_all_repo_pr_returns_valid_response(self):
        with ExitStack() as stack:

            mock_access_all_repo_pr = stack.enter_context(
                patch("GithubAPIpackage.GithubAPI._fetch_url")
            )
            fake_data = {"current_user_repositories_url": "http://myfakeurl.com"}
            mock_access_all_repo_pr.return_value = fake_data


            result = access_all_repo_pr()

            self.assertEqual(result, "")
```

Comment: did you resolve this issue? I want to test my pygithub based AWS lambda function as well. i was wondering what library to use for mocking Github API for python. where did you learn about magicmock? did it work well?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `requests` under the hood, may I suggest using [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) for your testing? Not trying to skirt the question, but in my experience, I have found this to be the path of least resistance when it comes to writing tests that deal with the `requests` module. The tests end up being a lot cleaner, safer, and easier to write.